# Goal completions by events custom report shows no data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to build a custom report showing the number of goal completions split by event (category/action/label).

Following the set-up outlined in [this forum answer](https://moz.com/community/q/google-analytics-events-that-lead-to-goals-conversions#reply_220457), I have created a report with the following configuration:
[image: GA custom report configuration]

The data in the resulting report is showing no goals completions for these events (yet sessions are correctly counted):
[image]

I have checked the following:

- This custom report works with other dimensions (e.g. landing page) - i.e. it shows data for goal completions.
- The goal > Overview report shows completions when segmented by the event categories/actions/labels in the custom report (so I know that there is data to show).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely related to mixing scopes. Events are hit-scoped whereas goals are session-scoped. Landing pages are also session-scoped which is why you're able to build the report using that as a dimension.